# PHP datatables / ajax : <td> in data

Tags: php, ajax, datatables

I need to update an old project - it has its own backend and does deliver row data as an array which gets displayed as a standard html table.

The last attribute in the row array has an "editing column" by default, which means, it contains markup for an edit-icon like this:

```
$aData = array(
    "first_name"    => "John",
    "last_name"     => "Connor",
    "edit_columns"  => "<a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a>"
);
```

The problem - there are also tables in my backend which will deliver several table cells (which works so far as it used to be a html table) with array data like this:

```
$aData = array(
    "first_name"    => "John",
    "last_name"     => "Connor",
    "edit_columns"  => "<a href='#' class='edit'>Edit</a> </td><td> <a href='#' class='delete'>Delete</a>"
);
```

The problem: the datatables plugin will treat `edit_columns` as a single cell and filter the `</td><td>` markup which results in 2 hyperlinks within one cell.

I know i would need to refactor my data but my customer wants to keep the backend data untouched. So - is there a way to "shift" the cell data as required?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, that we would need to create separate Columns in the backend + map it which would take too long (i think there are about 100 lists) ..

Comment: you have the column data, why can't you add new table html in edit_columns and add the column value to newly add table.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of datatables you are using you could listen to the `xhr.dt`-event with javascript and then modify/split the data before it gets rendered in your table.

```
myTable.on('xhr.dt', function (e, settings, json, xhr) {
  let data = json.data;
  for ( let i=0, dataLength=data.length; i<dataLength; i++ ) {
    let edit_columns = data[i].edit_columns.split("</td><td>");
    data[i].edit_column = edit_columns[0];
    data[i].delete_column = edit_columns[1];
  }
});
```

Now you can use the created data-columns *(`edit_column` and `delete_column`)* in your table like they are regular columns without modifying the code on the backend/serverside.